# Are those CPU temperature readings too high?

Tags: battery-life, overheating

System specs & state: windows 8 running 15" notebook, AMD dual core m340 CPU (from 2010), 8gb ram, newly cleaned fans and internals, no unnecessary background tasks running, laptop is elevated a little so fans are open, power saving mode turned on, 40% brightness.

Case 1: system idle, no background tasks, CPU temperature is around 55°c (130°f)

Case 2: only web browsing with 1-3 tabs open, CPU temp is around 65°c (150°f).

Case 3: Under relatively heavy usage such as Spotify, 8 chrome tabs, 2 word documents, a pdf document, Dropbox syncing, torrent downloading are the running tasks at the same time the temperature is around 80°c (180°f).

Question: Are those readings too high for a laptop? (here, the main concern is battery consumption rate) Also in any of the cases am I damaging my battery because of the excessive heat? Do I have to remove the battery and use my pc plugged in to prevent the damage?

Comment: Without knowing your ambient conditions, this seems pretty normal. My Early '14 MBPr with i7 is idling @ 55 on battery and heats up to 80 in a heartbeat. Notebooks have a much more "passive" approach to cooling, as fans eat power. The chips usually have a lower TDP so they can dissipate with little active airflow. I would start getting nervous if you had it hit TJmax-10 (in most cases TJmax is 100c or so).
TL;DR: 80 is OK, 90 is a bit suss, and anything above (under full load) is a worry.

Comment: You can also verify your power settings.  My notebook under 'High Performance' peaks at around 85°c, and drops to a little over 60°c at idle. Setting Power plan to Balanced actually drops the CPU temp down a few degrees (not much but slightly noticeable).